# How to filter top n records from hierarchical fields

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have 6 hierarchical fields: column1, column2, column3 etc. and next one is child of previous. I wanted to create filters which will shop top n (provided by user) of each column. So if i will put 2 for column1 and 5 for column2, i should see top 2 categories from column1 and top 5 from both these categories only. I tried to do it using parameter and in filter to go "Top ->By field -> Top top_n_column1 by TOTAL_GMV Sum" but it is not working properly. What are other ways to do it in Tableau Desktop?